# Retrieve substring with grep

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I've got a question concerning grep.

I have some address data in an asc file as simple text. The first 30 characters are for the name. If the name is shorter than the 30 characters whitespaces fill it up to ensure its length is 30. At position 31 is a whitespace to separate the name from the next data which is the address. After the address is also a whitespace and some other data. My plan is to retrieve the address, which starts at index 32 and continues to index 50. I mostly got only nothing or the data beginning at the start of the line. I tried several methods such as

```
grep -iE '^.{30}' '.{8}$' myfile.asc
```

or

```
grep –o -P '^.{31,34}' myfile.asc
```

I can't search for a certain pattern since every set of data is different except the whitespaces which separate the data. Is it possible to retrieve my substring like that without relying on other methods through a pipe? I prefer to use grep since performance is an issue.

Comment: I think `sed` could be more suitable for this.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use cut instead of grep if you're dealing with fixed positions?

```
cut -c 32-50 myfile.asc
```